# 8bit kinect data

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I search disparity and depth data 11bit.

But kinect pulish just 8bit.

Why do they have difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42299/8bit-kinect-data/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [openni_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) documentation on the ROS wiki, you can see that the `openni_node` broadcasts several topics.

I think for the data that you are looking for, the topics of interest will be the `depth/image_raw` messages, or the `depth_registered/image_raw` if you have the OpenNI registration turned on.

The */image_raw messages are in the [sensor_msgs/Image](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) message format, which stores the data in a byte array, that can then be reassembled in the subscriber.  This is accomplished using [cv_bridge](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge).

`cv_bridge` allows you to write code like this for your callback:

```
void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
  try
  {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::TYPE_32FC1);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
  }
  cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
  image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
}
```

`cv_ptr->image` will contain an OpenCV `cv::Mat`, in this case containing floating point values, which represent the depth in millimeters for that pixel.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-08-29**:
They might also be interested in the rectified images, `depth_registered/image_rect_raw`